# PHP Opencart Anylist Module issue

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-module

Does anyone knows what is this problem?
When I save or edit a new anylist block in opencart, this message appears:

```
Notice: Undefined index: module_id in /controller/module/anylist.php on line 16
```

This is the line 16 of the file:

```
    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
                if (!isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
                    /*this is the line 16*/
                    $this->model_extension_module->addModule('anylist', array_merge($this->request->post,array('module_id'=>$this->request->get['module_id'])));
                } else {
                    $this->model_extension_module->editModule($this->request->get['module_id'], array_merge($this->request->post,array('module_id'=>$this->request->get['module_id'])));
                }
                $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
                $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
            }
```

Does anybody knows what is the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This work for me.
You need replase this code

```
if (!isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
    /*this is the line 16*/
    $this->model_extension_module->addModule('anylist', array_merge($this->request->post,array('module_id'=>$this->request->get['module_id'])));
} else {
    $this->model_extension_module->editModule($this->request->get['module_id'], array_merge($this->request->post,array('module_id'=>$this->request->get['module_id'])));
}
```

on

```
if (!isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
    $this->model_extension_module->addModule('anylist', $this->request->post);
} else {
    $this->model_extension_module->editModule($this->request->get['module_id'], $this->request->post);
}
```